# How to find vector bounds in another program's memory

Tags: c++, linux, vector, reverse-engineering

Having recently been interested in memory editing I decided to have a play around with an old open source game I used to play a bit (liberal crime squad).

My "C/C++/Asm/GeneralMemory" knowledge is cursory at best but the first few things I tried went smoothly, using ptrace I managed to find a global pointer to an object which lead me to the `funds` variable and various other equally simple tasks. But then I tried to change the skills and attributes of you/you're teammates and realized that all the `Creature`s were stored in a `vector<Creature*>` (a C++ vector).

So avoiding the question `how are classes/objects stored in memory` for a later date my question is; Can I reliably find the length of a vector at runtime from another program and if so how?

To clarify I'm not asking for answers about how to find a vectors size from within a C++ program, but from another program which is currently inspecting it's memory.

**EDIT**

The purpose of this exercise is too learn more about the reality behind memory editing. Using information that wouldn't normally be available within that context (and by normally I mean access to source files or debugging symbols) is not useful to that end.

Also I'm very early along my path to learning C/C++ properly. While perhaps not met with the same level of enthusiasm books/texts/documentation to reference would still be invaluable.

#### Extra Details

Using GCC 6.3.1

Comment: If it's open source, why don't you just inspect the source files?

Comment: By "a vector", do you mean an instance of the C++ class `vector` or do you mean "vector" in the generic computer science sense? Also, what do you mean by "reliably"? Do you mean that it works fine in practice? Or do you mean it's guaranteed to work perfectly all the time?

Comment: Do research on how individual compilers manage the stack and then look at how the particular `vector` is implemented

Comment: @MichaelWalz The purpose of the exercise is to learn more about memory analysis rather than to learn more about this particular project. I chose an open source project is so I can check my own work. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is an instance of the C++ class vector. And as far as reliability is concerned, working in practice is fine. This is purely a personal project for sake of interest/knowledge.

Comment: Typical reveng approach: attach with a debugger, do a hexdump of the memory in question (if you know where it's located, good, if not, dump the whole memory and look for something identificative, maybe creature names?), look for something that looks like what you're after.

Comment: @ninjalj Cheers, I'll have another look after work, do as you say; find a pattern and see if I can't can't figure something out :)

Comment: @PasserBy I'm using GCC but (please correct me if I'm wrong) I was under the impression that gcc wouldn't allocate things to the stack unless it was allocated inside a function, this vector is defined outside of any function

Comment: That's actually what I meant, you have to get into the nitty gritty details of specifics for the particular library for a certain OS with certain hardware compiled by a certain compiler. There will be no general solution

Comment: Fair enough, I'll go do some reading then. Cheers guys